# "My first pro argument is..."

Tags: phrase-usage

My pupils often write "My first pro/con argument is..."
To my ears that doesn't sound natural, but is it wrong or just bad style, or maybe even correct?

Comment: I'm undecided, so a first approximation may be that it's only 50% correct (and 50% incorrect). Have you looked up 'pro' and 'con' in dictionaries for attributive usage, or checked "pro argument" etc in a Google search or on Google Ngrams (discarding pro = professional)?

Comment: They're showing linguistic competence, but linguistic competence does not always result in felicity and clarity. In that statement, by using **pro** and **con** as adjectives, they're leaving out some important information, what the argument is in support of or against. It could be a sign they're approaching the exercise as a chore.

Comment: There are over 1000 written contexts juxtaposing ["pro arguments" "con arguments"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pro+arguments%22+%22con+arguments%22). Some people may object to the usages, but it's all just a matter of opinion.

Comment: This is a matter of style. The usage feels awkward to me, but I wouldn't mark the student down for it.

Comment: You're the teacher. If you talk about "pro" or "con" or "pro/con" in class -- or use it in written material -- the students will repeat it. And if you use terms as if they were official names, they will pick that up, too. Half of the grammatical terminology used in questions here is incomprehensible because it originated in some ancient classroom, where it all seemed to make sense at the time.

Comment: @John Lawler 'Arguments for' is more idiomatic, but an unusual form for a  stand-alone expression.

Comment: @Edwin - Yes, and a student might well organize a comparison and contrast paper with "arguments for" versus "arguments against". (Someone once summarized Haj Ross's argumentation style as "16 arguments for and 5 arguments against, so we win.")

Comment: @John Sounds rather like the guy who said "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others." Though he wasn't usually involved in important stuff like acceptable English expressions.

Comment: ... I can imagine his English teacher's reaction to "To jaw-jaw is always better than to war-war." Detention for a week. _No cigars_ for a week.

Answer (score 0):

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pro) licenses the attributive usage (the adjective):

> **pro 1**  (prō) **n.** pl. pros
>
> 1. An argument or consideration in favor of something: *weighing the pros and cons*.
> 2. One who supports a proposal or takes the affirmative side in a debate.
>
> **adv.** In favor; affirmatively: *arguing pro and con*.
>
> **adj.**  Affirmative; supporting: *a pro vote*.

as CDO appears to, whereas Collins, RHK Webster's, M-W, and Dictionary.com don't give it. ODO gives it solely as part of a compound adjectival (pro business, pro free enterprise) rather than an independent adjective.

Raw Google searches show 64k hits for "pro argument" as compared with 49k for "pro vote".

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pro+vote%2Cpro+argument&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpro%20vote%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpro%20argument%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that 'pro argument' was three times as commonly used as 'pro vote' in 2000.

Personally, I don't like the sound of the usage and wouldn't choose to use it. But one can't label it 'incorrect' (I choose not to use 'I insist that he go to school' either).

Comment: The "go" in "I insist that he go to school" is subjunctive, correct? So you don't use the subjunctive tense?

Comment: (1) I rarely use the subjunctive **mood** (not tense, and according to some, not subjunctive either: check questions here) in such constructions. (2) In my opinion, the indicative is far more idiomatic in the UK. Periphrastic 'should' disambiguates better than either ("I insist that they should go to school"), but sounds rather stuffy in my opinion. All are said to be grammatical by ACGEL and CGEL, and context almost always disambiguates.